# Android Facebook login screen no keyboard

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

My application uses Facebook login. I have the Facebook application installed.

If an invalid **Facebook token** arrives (by changing the password), the next time the application starts, it is not possible to use keyboard on the login screen. As shown below, the field is selected and the keyboard is stil hidden.

[image: login screen keyboard not working]

In the same conditions if the Facebook application is opened first it will signal that the session is invalid and open the login screen. After this operation it is enough to open my application and the Facebook login sequence will work.

**NOTE: the login screen shown after this procedure inside my application is the login screen from the Facebook app, as shown in the picture below!!**

[image: different login screen]

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Any update on this? Same stuff happening on my S4.

Comment: Still present, no updates jet.

Comment: Filed a bug on Facebook using the link, if you don't mind.

Comment: I'm fine with it. Add a comment or edit my post with the link after you are done.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Seems Facebook already fixed this bug with their releases.

Comment: Did anyone find a workaround for this bug? It is still happening in my devices.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found the problem is: Facebook application on my device has session expire and need to login again. When I logged out , my app ran normally and the keyboard was showed.
I hope it will help you!

Comment: Is there any way to check if facebook session has expired and inform user about it?